# Wildfly 26 could not deploy a Servlet that extends from Jakarta HttpServlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-11, wildfly-26, jakarta-migration

I am using **Eclipse IDE** to create a simple Java web application. I am using **Wildfly 26**, **Java 11**. I run the web app inside the Eclipse. I created a **TestServlet** with @WebServlet("/TestServlet") with default generated implementation (Printing Servled at .... )

If the **TestServlet** extends from **javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet** -> The servlet was deployed successfully -> I can access http://localhost:8080/myapp/TestServet to see the servlet output.

BUT if the **TestServlet** extends from **jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet** -> The servlet was NOT deployed successfully -> http://localhost:8080/myapp/TestServet returns "**Not Found**".  Eclipse Console did not show any error messages relating to the Servlet deployment.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to migration our application from wildfly 9 to 24 and I found that we need to switch javax.servlet  package to jakarta.servlet package.  I did this changes and it seems my servlet not getting called and even application listner also not getting called.  Can we use javax.servlet ??  can you please help to fix the same with jarkarta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WildFly 26 is JakartaEE 8 compliant.
If you want to use JakartaEE 9 use WildFly 26 preview

Comment: Thank you. My mistake. I downloaded a wrong package.